# data inconsistency for simultaneous queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, multithreading

I have a insert query . And I want to fetch its id after its insertion , for which I am using mysql_insert_id() in php.

Now the problem which i was thinking about is that if two person are using the insert query in two different threads. so there will be 4 atomic query's.

```
$query="INSERT INTO `info`()  VALUES ()";
mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

If the two insert query gets executed first and then mysql_insert_id() is executed. so I will get  the recent article's id and 0..

So will there be data inconsistency ?

Comment: As an aside, stop using `mysql`, it's deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: if you ever get chance to see db request processing logs, you will find at tiny level, it processes each request in order(one by one). So, it will not ever happen that it will return same id twice.

Answer (score 2):

The [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function used is *connection-specific* so there is no problem with the presented example.

> With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column ..
>
> The ID that was generated *is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis*. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column *by that client*.

However, this "general problem" is solved by using [Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) *:cough:*

Comment: +1 from me. Also the fact that auto_increment must be primary, which is unique by default - prevents two of the same ever being inserted, even if all hell breaks loose.